# Is std::declval<void>() a valid expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, void, decltype

As far as I know, I cannot declare an rvalue reference to `void`.
As an example, the following code is ill-formed:

```
 void f(void &&v) { }
```

From [[20.2.6/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/declval) (function template declval) we have a declaration for `declval` that is:

```
template <class T>
add_rvalue_reference_t<T>
declval() noexcept;
```

Thus, `declval<void>` (let me say) *would result* in `void &&`, that I guessed it was ill-formed as well as in the previous example.

Anyway, the following minimal, working example compiles:

```
#include<utility>

int main() {
    decltype(std::declval<void>())* ptr = nullptr;
}
```

Note that the following is true too:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<void>()), void>::value, "!");
```

I would have expected it to be `void&&` as previously mentioned (or better, I was expecting it fails to compile).
Actually, it happens to be an rvalue reference for any other non-reference type.
As an example:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<int>()), int&&>::value, "!");
```

Is `declval<void>` a valid expression or not? Is the code above legal?
Why does the behavior in case of `void` is different than with any other type? (*For it wouldn't have worked otherwise* could be an answer, if the code is legal).

If it's legal, where does the standard allow that? I've not been able to find the case.
Of course, the standard says:

> The template parameter T of declval may be an incomplete type.

Anyway, here it would result in a non acceptable type (`void&&`) and it works around it discarding the rvalue reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`add_rvalue_reference<T>` only results in `T&&` if `T` is a referenceable type. So when `T` is `void`, the result is just `void`. This is also why you can `add_rvalue_reference<int&&>` and not get an error attempting to construct a reference to a reference. (Same with lvalue reference.)

Comment: Damnit. It's obvious now that you pointed it out. I didn't think of how `add_rvalue_reference` works, I was biased to `declval`. Thank you. Quite stupid a question indeed, but this is a good answer for those that will do the same mistake in future.

Comment: @skypjack: Actually, I did not know this was the case going in, your question prompted me to look. :) Good question.